# Getting virtual directories from IIS with powershell in an MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, virtual-directory

I have created my own custom IIS directory browser in MVC3 (C#) and have hit a rough spot.

Currently I am using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace to get virtual directories out which is working fine, however I thought I'd try with PowerShell as the Site class needs permission to a folder in the windows directory.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddCommand("import-module");
        ps.AddArgument("webadministration");
        ps.AddCommand("get-webvirtualdirectory");
        ps.AddParameter("Name", "Default");
        IEnumerable<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
```

Now default does in have fact two virtual directories, however when I run this peice of code no errors occur, all seems to work as expected however, the collection returned in "results" comes out empty..

Even more of a conundrum, when I call `import-module webadministration` then `get-webvirtualdirectory -name Default` directly into powershell it works as expected returning the list of two.

Comment: what if you change `ps.AddCommand("import-module");
 ps.AddArgument("webadministration");` with `ps.AddCommand("import-module").AddParameter("Name","webadministration");` ?

Comment: Same deal I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the IIS connection pool process is running with admin privileges.